# How do I get a specific object from an immutable js map by value?

Tags: javascript, immutability

I created an immutable map (with [Immutable-JS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)) from a list of objects:

```
var result = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 4}];
var map = Immutable.fromJS(result);
```

Now i want to get the object with `id = 4`.

Is there an easier way than this:

```
var object = map.filter(function(obj){
 return obj.get('id') === 4
}).first();
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Essentially, no: you're performing a list lookup by value, not by index, so it will always be a linear traversal.

An improvement would be to use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
var result = map.find(function(obj){return obj.get('id') === 4;});
```

Answer (score 15):

The first thing to note is that you're not actually creating a map, you're creating a list:

```
var result = [{'id': 2}, {'id': 4}];
var map = Immutable.fromJS(result);

Immutable.Map.isMap(map); // false
Immutable.List.isList(map); // true
```

In order to create a map you can use a `reviver` argument in your `toJS` call ([docs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/fromJS)), but it's certainly not the most intuitive api, alternatively you can do something like:

```
// lets use letters rather than numbers as numbers get coerced to strings anyway
var result = [{'id': 'a'}, {'id': 'b'}];
var map = Immutable.Map(result.reduce(function(previous, current) { 
    previous[ current.id ] = current;
    return previous;
}, {}));

Immutable.Map.isMap(map); // true
```

Now we have a proper Immutable.js map which has a get method

```
var item = Map.get('a'); // {id: 'a'}
```

Answer (score 4):

It may be important to guarantee the order of the array. If that's the case:

1. Use an OrderedMap
2. Do a set method on the OrderedMap at each iteration of your source array

The example below uses "withMutations" for better performance.

```
var OrderedMap = Immutable.OrderedMap


// Get new OrderedMap
function getOm(arr) {
    return OrderedMap().withMutations(map => {
        arr.forEach(item => map.set(item.id, item))
    })
}

// Source collection
var srcArray = [
    {
        id: 123,
        value: 'foo'
    },
    {
        id: 456,
        value: 'bar'
    }
]


var myOrderedMap = getOm(srcArray)

myOrderedMap.get(123)
// --> { id: 123, value: 'foo' }

myOrderedMap.toObject()
// --> { 123: {id: 123, value: 'foo'}, 456: {id: 456, value: 'bar'} }

myOrderedMap.toArray()
// --> [ {id: 123, value: 'foo'}, { id: 456, value: 'bar' } ]
```

Answer (score 4):

When using fromJS for array, you'll get List not map. It will be better and easier if you create a map. The following code will convert the result into Immutable map.

```
  const map = result.reduce((map, json) =>
    map.set(json.id, Immutable.fromJS(json))
  , Map());
```

Now, you can

```
   map.get('2');   //{'id': 2}
```

Note, if the result has nested structure and if that has array, it will be a List with the above code.

Answer (score 3):

With **ES2015 syntax** (and constants):

```
const result = map.find(o => o.get('id') === 4);
```

Comment: This is not ImmutableJS as the op requested.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan isn't this the exact same as the accepted answer, with a different syntax?

Answer (score -2):

Is there already a way thats easier? I don't know. but you can write your own function. Something like this should work:

```
var myFunc = function(id){

    var object = map.filter(function(obj){return obj.get('id') === id}).first();

    return object;
}
```

Then you would just do:
`var myObj = myFunc(4);`

Comment: yeah ok that's true, but that's not the point. maybe you're right and there's no "easier" way. I was hoping I missed some point in the Immutable documentation :)

Comment: @sspross, I wasn't sure if this would be what you wanted. It was my best-guess given that I haven't actually used Immutable (was hoping you just wanted a general JS solution).